# General and Faster Solution for a Linear Programming Problem?

Tags: linear-programming, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

Let $X=\{-1,1\}^n$ for a given natural number $n$ and $(w_0,w_2,\cdots,w_n)\in R_+^{n+1}$. Find
$$\min_{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\in X}\bigg|w_0+\sum_iw_ix_i\bigg|.$$

We can turn this into the following binary linear programming problem.
\begin{align}
\min_{{(x_1,\,x_2,\,\cdots,\,x_n)\in X}\atop{d}}&\ d \\
w_0+\sum_iw_ix_i&\le d \\
-(w_0+\sum_iw_ix_i)&\le d \\
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\min_{{(x_1,\,x_2,\,\cdots,\,x_n)\in X}\atop{s,\,t}}&\ s+t \\
w_0+\sum_iw_ix_i&=s-t \\
s&\ge 0 \\
t&\ge 0 
\end{align}

Is there a faster and general solution?

Comment: You are mixing two methods to reformulate absolute values. You can get rid of $d$ and define the objective as $s+t$.  As subset sum is a special case of your problem, I would not expect any fast solution method.

Comment: @LinAlg: You are right. I have edited the question. Is there a fast dynamic programming algorithm to solve this problem?